# Twilio CLI for Serverless & Ngrok

Tags: node.js, twilio, ngrok

Need some help trying to use the Twilio CLI and Ngrok together. How do I resolve the spawn UNKNOWN issue?

This command executes successfully, starts the function, and starts Ngrok:

```
npx twilio-run --ngrok=validpaidsubdomain
```

The version of twilio-run according to "npx twilio-run --version" is 3.5.3.

This command executes with an error:

```
twilio serverless:start --ngrok=validpaidsubdomain
```

The error says:

> ERROR
>
> spawn UNKNOWN

The version of the twilio-cli according to "twilio --version" is:

> twilio-cli/5.16.1
>
> win32-x64 node-v18.18.2

I have also tried this command which results in the same span UNKNOWN error:

```
twilio serverless:start --ngrok=validpaidsubdomain.ngrok.io
```

When I first start ngrok using this command:

> ngrok http 3000 --domain=validpaidsubdomain.ngrok.io

I can then successfully start the function using twilio serverless:start but the Twilio CLI console does not show the correct URLs, it will show localhost instead of validpaidsubdomain.ngrok.io.

The debug log from (twilio serverless:start --ngrok=validpaidsubdomain -l debug) shows the following:

```
twilio-run:config:configLoader Load config +0ms
  twilio-run:config:configLoader Config found at K:\xxxx.twilioserverlessrc +39ms
  twilio-run:cli:config Read .env file at "K:\xxxx.env" +0ms
  twilio-run:cli:config Overriding port via command-line flag to 3000 +2ms
  twilio-run:start Determined configuration: { baseDir: 'K:xxxx', env: { ACCOUNT_SID: '[REDACTED]', AUTH_TOKEN: '[REDACTED]' }, port: 3000, detailedLogs: false, live: true, logs: true, appName: 'twilio-run', forkProcess: true, pkgJson: { name: '[REDACTED]', version: '[REDACTED]', private: '[REDACTED]', scripts: '[REDACTED]', dependencies: '[REDACTED]', devDependencies: '[REDACTED]', engines: '[REDACTED]' } } +0ms
  twilio-run:start Set environment variables as: { ACCOUNT_SID: '[REDACTED]', AUTH_TOKEN: '[REDACTED]' } +3ms
  twilio-runtime-handler:dev:server Creating Local Development Server +0ms
  twilio-runtime-handler:dev:server @twilio/runtime-handler version: 1.3.0 +0ms
  twilio-runtime-handler:dev:server Creating server with config: { baseDir: 'K:xxxx', env: { ACCOUNT_SID: '[REDACTED]', AUTH_TOKEN: '[REDACTED]', DEBUG: '[REDACTED]' }, port: 3000, url: 'http://localhost:3000', detailedLogs: false, live: true, logs: true, appName: 'twilio-run', forkProcess: true, logger: { useDebugModule: true, options: { level: -1 } }, routes: { functions: [ [Object] ], assets: [ [Object] ] }, enableDebugLogs: true } +1ms
  twilio-runtime-handler:dev:runtime Found the following functions available: { 'xxx': { path: 'K:\xxxx.protected.js' } } +0ms
  twilio-run:start Start server on port 3000 +331ms
  twilio-run:cli:config Starting ngrok tunnel +337ms

│ ERROR
│
│ spawn UNKNOWN
```

Comment: I think the best way to contact the team would be via the [Github issues](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-cli)

Comment: OK, I will do that too. Thanks!